# Login Post Request, unable to authenticate users with nodejs Oracledb

Tags: node.js, forms-authentication, node-oracledb

I am passing user credentials (username & password) through a login form post request and trying to check against the database (oracledb) and if the credentials match then render another page.

However i keep getting an "Authentication failed" error despite the credentials matching

```
 app.post("/", async function(req, res) {
   
    let connection;  
        const {username,password}=req.body;
        const sqlquery = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = :username AND PASSWORD = :password';
       connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

      let result = await connection.execute(
       sqlquery , {username,password} ,function(err,result){
           if (err) {
               console.error('Error executing the query:', err);
               return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
             }
      const userCount = result.rows[0];
      console.log(userCount);
      if (userCount === 1) {
       return res.render("playercentre");
      } else {
       return res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');
      }
       }
       
      );
      
  });
```

The console.log(userCount) returns 1 but still i get the error instead of rendering the page. Not sure where i am missing something.

Comment: i fixed it but i completely changed my code to apply hashed password so this is not relevant anymore

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read this great post about [loose vs strict equality](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/loose-vs-strict-equality-in-javascript/).
Briefly, loose (`==`) checks the value, and **performs type coercion** if necessary.
Strict (`===`) checks **both the value and the type**

In your case, I assume `result.rows[0]` returned the string "1".
Although `1 == "1"` results in `true` because the value is 1, `1 === "1"` result in false because one is a number, and the second is a string.

There are other ways to fix it rather than change your condition to loose equality.
Otherwise, it might cause some unexpected bugs in the future.
Generally speaking, in case `result.rows[0]` returned `true` or the string `"1"`, it could be something you want to detect, and maybe throw an error (for this unexpected value in the row).